# how to make the calculation work on multiple products?

Tags: javascript

I was creating the shopping cart page and I would like to do a calculation based on the price of the product and the quantity, I have implemented this aspect with lines in Javascript but it does not work for all the products on the page.

Could anyone help me? Thank you very much!

```js
function multiply() {
  var form1 = document.getElementById("multiply");
  var multiplicand = form1.elements["multiplicand"].value;
  var multiplier = form1.elements["multiplier"].value;
  var product = multiplicand * multiplier;
  document.getElementById("product").textContent = "= " + product; 
};

multiply();
```

```html
<div class="title">
<h2 class="font-weight-bold pt-5">Shopping Cart</h2>
<hr class="new2">
</div>
<div class="cartcontainer">
<table width="100%">
 <thead>
   <tr>
      <td>Remove</td>
      <td>Image</td>
      <td>Product</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Total</td>
   </tr> 
 </thead>
 
  <tbody>
   
     <tr>
       <td><a class="btn-remove" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
       <td><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang2.jpg" alt=""></td>
       <td><h5>Big Bang Standard</h5></td>
       <form id="multiply"><td><input type="number" name="multiplicand" value="33.00" readonly>&nbsp;$</td>
       <td><input type="number" name="multiplier" value="1"></td>
       <td><input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="multiply()">&nbsp;<label id="product"></label>.00 $</td></form> 
       <script  src="./script.js"></script>
     </tr>  

     <tr>
       <td><a class="btn-remove" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
       <td><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang1.jpg" alt=""></td>
       <td><h5>Big Bang Premium</h5></td>
       <form id="multiply"><td><input type="number" name="multiplicand" value="39.00" readonly>&nbsp;$</td>
       <td><input type="number" name="multiplier" value="1"></td>
       <td><input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="multiply()">&nbsp;<label id="product"></label>.00 $</td></form> 
       <script  src="./script.js"></script>
     </tr>  

     <tr>     
       <td><a class="btn-remove" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
       <td><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang4.jpg" alt=""></td>
       <td><h5>Big Bang Deluxe</h5></td>
       <form id="multiply"><td><input type="number" name="multiplicand" value="42.00" readonly>&nbsp;$</td>
       <td><input type="number" name="multiplier" value="1"></td>
       <td><input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="multiply()">&nbsp;<label id="product"></label>.00 $</td></form> 
       <script  src="/script.js"></script>
     </tr>   
   

  </tbody> 
 
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, an identifier must be unique in the document according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)

> The id property of the Element interface represents the element's identifier, reflecting the id global attribute.

> If the id value is not the empty string, it must be unique in a document.

In your code you are defining 3 times the `multiply` identifier.

So when you're retrievng the form with the line `var form1 = document.getElementById("multiply");` it will always return the first one.

---

What you can do to solve your problem is adding an index to the `multiply` and retrieve this index with the [Element#querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) method.

This can be done either directly in the HTML, or with javascript by looping over all the rows.

Note that to retrieve the child element you can add custom attributes as I did with `myLabel`

---

```js
function multiply(index) {
  const table = document.getElementById("myTable")
  const row = table.querySelectorAll('tr')[index]
  const form1 = row.querySelector('form')
  var multiplicand = form1.elements["multiplicand"].value;
  var multiplier = form1.elements["multiplier"].value;
  var product = multiplicand * multiplier;
  console.log(product)
  row.querySelector("label[my-label]").textContent = "= " + product; 
};
```

```html
<div class="title">
<h2 class="font-weight-bold pt-5">Shopping Cart</h2>
<hr class="new2">
</div>
<div class="cartcontainer">
<table width="100%">
 <thead>
   <tr>
      <td>Remove</td>
      <td>Image</td>
      <td>Product</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Total</td>
   </tr> 
 </thead>
 
  <tbody id="myTable">
   
     <tr>
       <td><a class="btn-remove" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
       <td><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang2.jpg" alt=""></td>
       <td><h5>Big Bang Standard</h5></td>
       <form><td><input type="number" name="multiplicand" value="33.00" readonly>&nbsp;$</td>
       <td><input type="number" name="multiplier" value="1"></td>
       <td><input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="multiply(0)">&nbsp;<label my-label></label>.00 $</td></form> 
       <script  src="./script.js"></script>
     </tr>  

     <tr>
       <td><a class="btn-remove" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
       <td><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang1.jpg" alt=""></td>
       <td><h5>Big Bang Premium</h5></td>
       <form><td><input type="number" name="multiplicand" value="39.00" readonly>&nbsp;$</td>
       <td><input type="number" name="multiplier" value="1"></td>
       <td><input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="multiply(1)">&nbsp;<label my-label></label>.00 $</td></form> 
       <script  src="./script.js"></script>
     </tr>  

     <tr>     
       <td><a class="btn-remove" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
       <td><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang4.jpg" alt=""></td>
       <td><h5>Big Bang Deluxe</h5></td>
       <form ><td><input type="number" name="multiplicand" value="42.00" readonly>&nbsp;$</td>
       <td><input type="number" name="multiplier" value="1"></td>
       <td><input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="multiply(2)">&nbsp;<label my-label></label>.00 $</td></form> 
       <script  src="/script.js"></script>
     </tr>   
   

  </tbody> 
 
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The user experience will probably be even nicer if you calculate everything automatically, with the user not having to click any buttons:

```js
function calc(ev){ // multiply price and amount:
 let tr=ev.target.closest("tr");
 inps=tr.querySelectorAll("input");
 tr.querySelector("td:last-child").textContent=inps[0].value*inps[1].value+" $";
 if(ev.type) ctotal() // update total sum
}
function ctotal(){ // total of last columns:
 total.textContent=[...tb.querySelectorAll("td:last-child")].reduce((a,c)=>parseFloat(c.textContent)+a,0);
}
const [total,tb]=["span","tbody"].map(e=>document.querySelector(".cartcontainer "+e));
tb.addEventListener("input",calc);
tb.onclick=ev=>{ // remove buttons ...
 if(ev.target.tagName==="BUTTON") ev.target.closest("tr").remove();
 ctotal();
}
// do initial calculations:
[...tb.children].forEach(t=>calc({target:t}));
ctotal();
```

```css
td input {width:35px}
td:nth-child(n+4) {white-space:nowrap}
```

```html
<div class="title">
<h2 class="font-weight-bold pt-5">Shopping Cart</h2>
<hr class="new2">
</div>
<div class="cartcontainer">
Total value of cart: <span></span> $
<table width="100%">
 <thead>
   <tr>
      <td>Remove</td>
      <td>Image</td>
      <td>Product</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Total</td>
   </tr> 
 </thead>
 <tbody
   <tr><td><button>remove</button</td>
       <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/109/200/150" alt=""></td>
       <td>Standard</td>
       <td><input type="number" value="33.00" readonly>&nbsp;$</td>
       <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
       <td></td></tr>  
   <tr><td><button>remove</button</td>
       <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/106/200/150" alt=""></td>
       <td>de luxe</td>
       <td><input type="number" value="39.00" readonly>&nbsp;$</td>
       <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
       <td></td></tr>  
   <tr><td><button>remove</button</td>
       <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/107/200/150" alt=""></td>
       <td>exclusive</td>
       <td><input type="number" value="43.00" readonly>&nbsp;$</td>
       <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
       <td></td></tr>  
   <tr><td><button>remove</button</td>
       <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/108/200/150" alt=""></td>
       <td>superior</td>
       <td><input type="number" value="53.00" readonly>&nbsp;$</td>
       <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
       <td></td></tr>  
   </table>
```